# Problem with Archpack addon in blender (traceback most recent call last)

Tags: python, add-on, archipack-add-on

I am having a problem with the Archpack addon, it was working normally, and suddenly started showing this error every time I had to add a new object in the scene: **traceback (most recent call last)**

The addon is working correctly, because I can add items in a new file, but I'm not able to use it in my project I'm working on, I've already disabled the addon several times, and even uninstalled it and reinstalled it, unfortunately I don't understand pytom to correct the problem manually (I have no idea what it might be, I've read what appears written several times, but I can't understand it) what could it be?

**Thanks a lot for the help!**
Here is a printscreen of the error.

[image]

Comment: Hello, try unhiding all objects with ALT H

Comment: Or more exactly try toggling the visibility of the object "Roof.002"

Comment: Hello, I just tried this, but unfortunately it didn't work, it still displays the error when adding any object, I also can't edit the walls, they even show the manipulation arrows, but when I try to increase the size, they bug.
Thanks for listening!